# ValueError when using numpy.fft for a simple list of numbers

Tags: python, fft

I am trying to calculate the FFT of a time series and it returns the following error:

```
ValueError: First argument must be a complex or real sequence of single or double precision
```

In my case I do not understand where the problem is. I am trying to apply the FFT to a quite simple array:

```
    print a 
# it returns the following
[13.3134 14.7837 15.8005 16.4392 16.77 16.8581 16.7637 16.542 16.2432
 15.9124 15.5899 15.0917 14.8813 14.6577 15.0892 15.5698 16.0618 16.5171
 16.5566 16.9148 17.0253 16.7795 16.5438 16.3472 16.1904 16.1334 16.1793
 16.2207 16.5104 16.3991 16.3626 16.2521 15.9728 15.5024 15.1352 15.1922
 15.313 15.5319 15.6566 15.9806 15.9293 15.9144 15.5511 15.1222 14.429
 13.536 12.9806 12.2661 11.7088 10.9465 10.3404 10.0313 9.9171 9.8158
 9.8581 10.0664 10.3319 10.3305 10.2444 9.9141 9.468 8.8006 8.0059 7.4783
 7.2678 7.0964 6.9787 6.6364 6.3546 6.2521 6.0148 6.0349 6.0132 6.0114
 6.2272 6.2661 6.5629 6.6819 7.1226 7.5229 7.69 7.4745 6.9349 6.3342
 6.0967 5.9438 5.7074 5.3418 5.0442 4.8068 4.6385 4.5081 4.4273 4.336
 4.2634 4.2024 4.0722]

import numpy as np
print np.fft.fft(a)
```

If instead of that vector I generate a random sequence of normally distributed values everything is fine. What is different in my array?

The type of a is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` and the type of a[0] is `<type 'float'>`

Comment: Are you sure you do not need to make an instance of an object?

Comment: What is the `type` of `a`, and what is the `type` of `a[0]`?

Comment: a :  <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
a (0) : <type 'float'>

Comment: show us how you initialize 'a'

Comment: @Martin 
`a` is loaded from a cvs file using `pd.read_cvs`. The file contains several columns, `a` is is initialized to be equal to one of them.

Comment: @3sm1r did you try dataframe.as_matrix() or dataframe.value ? You need to pass pure numpy array. Just for the record, I tried the array you posted and it worked fine for me. I had datatype float64

Comment: Thank you @Martin ! I'll try with that.